# How to hide the form permanently and display form submitted

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Can someone suggest me how to hide the form from a user once they have submitted successfully and display the message form submitted and this should be visible to the user each time they log in? So far, I am able to collect and save the information to MySQL database. If you need the code I would add it here. Any help truly appreciated.

```
                                   OR
```

How can I disable the entire form upon submit and still display all the data entered in the form field permanently? Please help me with the approach I am desperate to find the answer for this.Thank you

Comment: Just fetch the data from the database. If it doesn't exist, show the form and if it does, don't show the form. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thank you, till now I have saved the form into DB and I am using http://garlicjs.org/#requirements to persistently display the submitted data in the fields. But not fetching anything from the database. I have updated my question please find the same.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would change anything. When a user login, just check the database (you say you store the form in the DB) if the user have submitted the form or not. Just because you're not doing that now doesn't mean that you can't start doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ajax

```
$("form").css("display", "initial");     
event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action     
var post_url =  //get form action url    
var request_method =  //get form GET/POST method  
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission      
$.ajax({                                  
url: post_url,                                   
type: request_method,                                  
data: form_data                              
}).done(function (response) { //                                 
$(".form").css("display", "none");                                   
$("#results").html(response);                                                                  
});
```

when getting response display : none the form

Answer (score 2):

While submitting data in database make an entry of is_form_submitted as true. When users logs in, you just need to check is_form_submitted. If its true, so can hide form else you can show the form.

If you are using an AJAX for form submission, then on AJAX's success response, you can hide the form.

In HTML, you can add `disply:'none'` css for hiding form.

Comment: Thanks, will try this approach

Comment: For your OR question, you can fetch the data from database and show it on form.

Comment: Great but, how to approach that?

Comment: Whenever users logs into your application, by using userId or Token, you can fetch the form data(I am considering you have one table which submits form data associating with userId), If it gives you 0 result, you can show empty form, else you can show the fetched data on form. If user is having data in form, then for next time you just need to update the record. Hope it will help you :)